# How to create an iframe modal form pre described js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a js file called makeIframeModal.js . Normally when i try to create an iframe, is use the iframe tag in jsp like this :

```
<iframe id="myIframeId" style="display:none;" height="430" width="675" src="myjsp.jsp" ></iframe>
```

Now makeIframeModal.js contains the iframe description like this :

```
iframemodal = new modal($('framebtn'), {

afterOpen : function(){$$('.close a').invoke('observe','click',function(e){modal.close(); Event.stop(e);});},
opacity: 0.3,
width: 675,
fade: true,
fadeDuration: 0.1,
autoOpenIfLinked: false

});
```

So , my iframe opens up in a pop up. Now I have a link in this iframe, which when clicked will close the iframe. This i am doing like this :

```
function closeMyIframe()
{
var parentDynamicDiv = window.parent.document.getElementById('dynamic_id1');
var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('dynamic_id2');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
parentDynamicDiv.style.display = 'none';
}
```

However, now i need to open up another iframe called myNewIframeModal.

So in short: When i close the first iframe another iframe must open up in a pop up automatically. How can achieve I this functionality ? Kindly help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call the new modal inside the closeMyframe...

```
function closeMyIframe()
{
var parentDynamicDiv = window.parent.document.getElementById('dynamic_id1');
var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('dynamic_id2');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
parentDynamicDiv.style.display = 'none';

iframemodal2 = new modal($('framebtn'), {

afterOpen : function(){$$('.close a').invoke('observe','click',function(e){modal.close(); Event.stop(e);});},
opacity: 0.3,
width: 675,
fade: true,
fadeDuration: 0.1,
autoOpenIfLinked: false

});

}
```

Comment: Where and how do i add my jsp , which will contain the contents of the new modal . Further more, i tried  out this way, the new modal is not popping up after the old modal is closed .

Comment: please provide me the modal lib u r using??..the way u wrote the code doesnt help to create new popup..